# Line charts by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data and I want to create a line chart conditional on `group1` and `group2` variable.

```
dat <- structure(list(group1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                                         .Label = c("a", "b"),
                                         class = "factor"),
                      group2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L),
                      val1 = c(10L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 2L),
                      val2 = c(8L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 8L),
                      val3 = c(7L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 6L)),
                 .Names = c("group1", "group2", "val1", "val2", "val3"),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Ideally, I want to have two graphs based on `group1`(two for levels `a` and `b`) and within each `group`1 variable I need line charts based on the row variables(basically connecting three points for `val1`, `val2`, and `val3`) with different colors for different `group2` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
dat2 <- with(dat, data.frame(group1 = rep(group1, each = 3), 
                             group2 = factor(rep(group2, each = 3)), 
                             values = stack(dat[,3:5])[,1]))
```

The above code restructures the data into a format more easily used with ggplot. `dat` was defined using the `dput()` code I added to your Q. The plot I think you want can be produced via

```
p <- ggplot(dat2, aes(x = 1:3, y = values, colour = group2)) + geom_line() + 
        geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ group1, ncol = 2)
p
```

which gives

[image: ggplot line plot example]

I've basically had to make up some `x` data otherwise how do you know where in the x- and y-coordinate space the points should be located?

Comment: Thank you for the solution.I understand the lack of intuition for the lack of x data, but it is a date variable and I don't want to get into the hassle of dealing with date variables in R.