# How to create an individual line plot in between box plot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, line-plot

I'm trying to create a plot like this image below where the individual data lines are in between the box plots. [Image to create in R ggplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQNTh.png)

The closest I am getting is something like this:
[Image using ggplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Jkt.png) but it looks a bit cluttered with the lines/points behind.

```
data1 %>%
ggplot(aes(Time,Trait)) +
geom_line(aes(group=ID), position = "identity")+
geom_point(aes(group=ID), shape=21, colour="black", size=2, position = "identity")+
geom_boxplot(width=.5,position = position_dodge(width=0.9), fill="white") +
stat_summary(fun.data= mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1,  position = position_dodge(width = .9)) +
stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 18, size=3, position = "identity")+
facet_wrap(~Cond) +
theme_classic()
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello Erich, very nice question. Could you post part of your data?

Comment: Previous related discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605926/how-to-draw-a-plot-joining-points-from-two-measurement-times/15606055

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of continuous x scale. Doing so makes it possible to shift the box plots  to the left or to right and vice versa for the points and lines:

Making use of some random data to mimic your real data set.

```r
data1$Time1 <- as.numeric(factor(data1$Time, levels = c("Pre", "Post")))
data1$Time_box <- data1$Time1 + .1 * ifelse(data1$Time == "Pre", -1, 1)
data1$Time_lp <- data1$Time1 + .1 * ifelse(data1$Time == "Pre", 1, -1)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data1, aes(x = Time_box, y = Trait)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Time_lp, group=ID), position = "identity")+
  geom_point(aes(x = Time_lp, group=ID), shape=21, colour="black", size=2, position = "identity")+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Time_box, group=Time1), width=.25, fill="white") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 18, size=3, position = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2), labels = c("Pre", "Post")) +
  facet_wrap(~Cond) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(42)

data1 <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:10, 4),
  Time = rep(c("Pre", "Post"), each = 10),
  Trait = runif(40),
  Cond = rep(c("MBSR", "SME"), each = 20)
)
```

**EDIT** If you want to two boxplots side by side it's basically the same. However in that case you have to map the `interaction` of `Time1` and the variable mapped on `fill` on the `group` aesthetic in `geom_boxplot` (and probably the error bars as well):

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

data1 <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:10, 4),
  Time = rep(c("Pre", "Post"), each = 10),
  Fill = rep(c("Fill1", "Fill2"), each = 5),
  Trait = runif(40),
  Cond = rep(c("MBSR", "SME"), each = 20)
)

ggplot(data1, aes(x = Time_box, y = Trait)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Time_lp, group=ID, color = Fill), position = "identity")+
  geom_point(aes(x = Time_lp, group=ID, fill = Fill), shape=21, colour="black", size=2, position = "identity")+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Time_box, group=interaction(Time1, Fill) , fill = Fill), width=.25) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 18, size=3, position = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2), labels = c("Pre", "Post")) +
  facet_wrap(~Cond) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the speedy response! Very helpful. Works great! Now if I want to add another boxplot (fill group) to each pre/post (so it appears in the legend), how would I do this? position_dodge doesn't seem to work with the boxplot...

Comment: Basically it's the same. But you have to set the `group`ing right to make it work.